# Mouse over action in Protractor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

I am new to Protractor. Can anyone tell me how can we use Actions like mouse over,drag and drop(like Actions in Selenium) in Protractor. I need just a syntax or a code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually there, inside the Protractor API documentation: [`.actions()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions):

```
browser.actions().
    mouseDown(element1).
    mouseMove(element2).
    mouseUp().
    perform();
```

A common problem is to forget calling `perform()` at the end which may results into it doing nothing. We actually had a weird test that had an action chain without the `perform()` and, because of the incorrect expectation the test just passed. You can catch [these types of problems](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/missing-perform.md) statically now, with [`eslint-plugin-protractor`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) (shameless self-promotion).